# How to disable extra feed / separator page after print job with EPL2 on a Zebra printer?

Tags: zebra-printers, epl

I am printing labels on a Zebra ZT410 by sending EPL2 commands to this printer. I am using continioues labels. The label is printed correctly but the length of the label is not correctly. It is double the length.

Example:

```
N
ZT
q480
Q240,0
LW0,0,480,240
A152,96,0,1,2,2,N,"TEXT"
A27,21,0,1,2,3,N,"TEXT"
P1
```

The label should be 30mm long. But the label is 60mm long.
If I press the FEED-button on the printer it feeds a 30mm long label.
So I guess that the printer is appending extra feed / separator page after each print job.

Does anybody now how I can prevent this?

Comment: you're manually setting the label length with the Q command. Typically, if a printer has a gap sensor, it will be able to determine the label length itself and will usually forward the last label as far as needed for the configured mode (e.g. tear-off). I'd also set the outer LW paramaters a bit lower for a start, e.g. LW0,0,470,235 to make sure the printer doesn't exceed the label dimensions. Or even better, start with only a single text at top left and start adding the rest and check when the printer starts feeding the second label to find the command that causes this.

Comment: If I use labels with gaps everything is working. I only have this problem if I am using continuous labels without gaps. I already tried to print only one single text in the middle of the label, but this still gives me the same result. 
If I use "LO" (black line) command instead of "LW" (white line) command I can see that the black rectangle exceeds the 30mm. It seems that there is a 5mm vertical offset. But I don't know where this vertical offset comes from and how I can prevent this.